# Query works in mysqlyog query window but not in php script?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables I am selecting from them 1 I want to get the user information and 2 I want to get all images belonging to the user . but the query  does not retrieve the images but in query window I get them . Also in the script if I decide to select from the images table the images are displayed but when I do the joining stuff it does not work. I know there is something am not doing well . please any help will be appreciated 
Bellow is the code

```
$query='SELECT 
tish_clientinfo.lastname, tish_clientinfo.address,
tish_clientinfo.firstname,
tish_images.image_name
  FROM  tish_clientinfo 
  INNER JOIN tish_images 
ON tish_clientinfo.user_id = tish_images.user_id
 WHERE user_id= '. intval($_GET['user_id']);
$result = $con->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: what is the data type of `user_id`?

Comment: @JW. int is the data type of user_id

Comment: he is converting to int,so it should be int. how do you mean in query window you see them? did you check if get variable exist? also you have two user_id variables, maybe you should pick one from either table in WHERE

Comment: Specify the table name whose user id you are comparing the value in the `WHERE` clause. As both of your table are having user_id. Change it to `tish_clientinfo.user_id`

Comment: @BojanKovacevic I mean if I put the same query In mysql query wizard it gets all the data am targeting .So u mean I should Delete ON tish_clientinfo.user_id = tish_images.user_id

Comment: @humphrey: please copy & paste the error you get.

Comment: no,that part should be ok. in any case,you should set either tish_clientinfo.user_id or tish_images.user_id in where. also make sure your get value is set. did you print $query variable?

Comment: @Meherzad it was the problem thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the server got confused about `user_id`. Try this

```
$query='SELECT 
tish_clientinfo.lastname, tish_clientinfo.address,
tish_clientinfo.firstname,
tish_images.image_name
  FROM  tish_clientinfo 
  INNER JOIN tish_images 
ON tish_clientinfo.user_id = tish_images.user_id
 WHERE tish_clientinfo.user_id= '. intval($_GET['user_id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just having a little problem  just after the where clause on the user_id specify the table just like I have done in the bellow answer

```
$query='SELECT 
tish_clientinfo.lastname, tish_clientinfo.address,
tish_clientinfo.firstname,
tish_images.image_name
  FROM  tish_clientinfo 
  INNER JOIN tish_images 
ON tish_clientinfo.user_id = tish_images.user_id
 WHERE tish_clientinfo.user_id= '. intval($_GET['user_id']);
$result = $con->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
```